# How can I set JavaFX dialog height?

Tags: java, javafx, alert

How can I set JavaFX alert height in which dialog's `contentText` is `null`? I made an alert and set `contentText` as null, but dialog's `contentText` field's height does not became smaller. How can I make `contentText` field's height as minimum?

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("title");
alert.setHeaderText("I want to make dialog without contenttext");
alert.setContentText(null);    //this is null but this field is still remain
```

I just tried like this.

```
alert.getDialogPane().setMaxHeight(10); //does not work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this method you can customize the size of the alert.

```
alert.getDialogPane().setMaxSize(2,2);
```

**Default Preview**

[image]

**Preview after the code**

[image]